# Handling asynchronous events with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have 3 asynchronous events which can only be run one after the other. When the first asynchronous event is completed, the second is run. When the second event is completed, the third is run. My code is as shown:

```
asynchronousEvent1(parameters1, function () { // Do stuff
    asynchronousEvent2(parameters2, function () { // Do stuff
        asynchronousEvent3(parameters3, function () { // Do stuff
        });
    });
});
```

This current format means that I need to have long sequences of functions nested within another. Is there some sort of an event handler I could use, for which the format of the code would be approximately:

```
asynchronousEvent1(parameters1, function () { /* Do stuff */ });
whenEvent1Completed(asynchronousEvent2(parameters2, function () { /* Do stuff */ });
whenEvent2Completed(asynchronousEvent3(parameters3, function () { /* Do stuff */ });
```

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for? http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`deferred` objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) introduced in jQuery 1.5. Assuming your functions return deferred objects, like the one returned by `$.ajax` (or of course you can create your own):

```
asynchronousEvent1(parameters1).pipe(function() {
    // do stuff
    return asynchronousEvent2(parameters2);
}).pipe(function() {
    // do stuff
    return asynchronousEvent3(parameters3);
}).then(function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

Have a look at the last example in [`deferred.pipe` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't necessarily consider this to be an answer, but more of an idea. I don't know how in real life your code is laid out, but would there be the possibility of using an array loaded with the functions to call in their order. Then, it just checks for the next one in the list, and calls that? I don't know would work, but it's an idea.

JMax

Comment: How do I determine when each event is completed?

Comment: It would call another function. I could envision using eval calling whatever method you had in your array. That would be very extensible. Just musing here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand what you're looking for.

You can, for example, define a function that handles the results of Event 1, and then simply pass a reference to that function instead of writing the literal at the spot where your chain is defined. If you use that pattern, you'd probably have to tweak how parameters are passed from one event to the second.

E.g.:

```
function handleEvent1() {
   // do something
   asynchronousEvent2(parameters2, handleEvent2);
}

function handleEvent2() {
   // do something
   asynchronousEvent3(parameters3, handleEvent3);
}

asyncronousEvent1(parameters1, handleEvent1);
```

In this example, none of these event handlers benefit from the same closure as they would in your original implementation, which means you'll need to work out some data visibility stuff.

Comment: The problem with that is that the code become inflexible. Because then each time Event1 is called, the other 2 events also get called. Sometimes, I just want to call event 1.

Answer (score 0):

set a value to true on each event callback and put condition for firing each dependent event.

```
$('blah').animate({},1000,function(){animated = true}
if(animated){$('blahblah').animate()...}
```

Comment: What if the line `if(animated)` is called before `animate()` has finished. Then the second `animate()` will never be called!

Comment: But I always call the other function in callback. I don't know why you don't like it?